# mobile page: dynamically created image sporadic loading

Tags: image, mobile

i have a page for a small mobile site that has an image that has its src value set via a getImage.aspx method, wherein an image is dynamically built and returned to the image tag. Most of the time it works great. However, there are moments where the image just doesnt load on the first shot. Hitting refresh helps most of the time, but I'd like to have this image load every time. Anyone else have this issue and moved beyond it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never had the issue with an dynamic image not loading without code errors.  A suggestion would be to move the image generation to a handler instead of a page to avoid the additional overhead.  It could be the async requests on the mobile devices getting limited.